# Content Security Policy error while loading a script

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, content-security-policy

i am trying to render a chart in my app using Pug as seen below:

```
block content
  h2 Question statistics
    .col-lg-12 
      script(src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js")
      .chart-container
        canvas#myChart2      
          script.
            var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart2").getContext('2d');
            ctx.canvas.parentNode.style.width = '50%'
            var idata = [1]    
            var ilabel = [2] 
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, { /* ... etc */
```

This was loaded just fine before a week or so but today when i tried to access this feature the chart would not render.
The error in my console is this:

> Refused to load the script
> `'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js'`
> because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
> `"script-src 'self'"`. Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly
> set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

and

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
> Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Either the
> 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
> ('sha256-AklvVxShqs4WBi3vUz7qSiPkes2rSVGoNyoZXYVnSA8='), or a nonce
> ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

This is the first time i am seeing this error and i don't know how to solve it. Any ideas?

Comment: Which backend is used to serve this? It's particularly interesting to know what component - or module - is responsible for setting up HTTP Headers in the response. Could you open the source code of the page and check its headers section?

Comment: @raina77ow this is being served with node js

Comment: Yep, and with JavaScript, and with HTTP. I can see that. It's details that matters here. What exactly creates HTTP Headers? Why did it change recently?

Comment: In particular, is there something like `response.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", ...` in the code? Does the 'real' server sit behind nginx or any other proxy?

Comment: no it is just res.send('chart.pug')

Comment: hitting it from postman i saw the value in Content-Security-Policy header of the response but i don't know if it would help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234500/discussion-between-raina77ow-and-epitheoritis-32).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As turned out in comments, here's the line of code that broke it all:

```
app.use(helmet());
```

[Helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet) is a really neat module designed to let you protect your server from the most common attack vectors without worrying much about details. Alas, as any good security tool, it operates in 'paranoid mode' by default. Here's what this small line is actually equivalent to:

```
app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy());
app.use(helmet.dnsPrefetchControl());
app.use(helmet.expectCt());
app.use(helmet.frameguard());
app.use(helmet.hidePoweredBy());
app.use(helmet.hsts());
app.use(helmet.ieNoOpen());
app.use(helmet.noSniff());
app.use(helmet.permittedCrossDomainPolicies());
app.use(helmet.referrerPolicy());
app.use(helmet.xssFilter());
```

Yep, a lot of stuff. The one that messed up your setup is the first item of this list. Here's the default values sent as [Content-Security-Policy header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) [values](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp) by that line:

```
default-src 'self';
base-uri 'self';
block-all-mixed-content;
font-src 'self' https: data:;
frame-ancestors 'self';
img-src 'self' data:;
object-src 'none';
script-src 'self';
script-src-attr 'none';
style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';
upgrade-insecure-requests
```

Once again, that makes sense, as Helmet doesn't know anything about external entities you're using - and your level of trust to those. It's you who are responsible for providing this data, either by adding hash info or by listing the trusted sources in the configuration. For example:

```
helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
  useDefaults: false,
  directives: {
    defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
    scriptSrc: ["'self'", "example.com"], // scripts from example.com are now trusted
    objectSrc: ["'none'"],
    upgradeInsecureRequests: [],
  },
})
```

You can configure each module individually, or add this configuration into helmet directly:

```
app.use(
  helmet({
    contentSecurityPolicy: {
      useDefaults: false,
      directives: { ... }
    },
  })
);
```